# Flex with container content that scrolls vs expanding the container

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to implement a flex layout that creates the layout below. The actual creation has proven to be relatively simple, but my challenge is that I want the panels to remain relative in size based on their proportions, but if I add content to the panels, such as the bottom left, it forces the panel to grow and I would prefer it either scrolled, or hid the overflow. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: I think that is more a task for CSS Grid than for a flex(ible) layout.

Comment: Interesting, ok, I'll go have a look at that.